# Web API download locks file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a small issue with a WebAPI method that downloads a file when the user calls the route of the method.

The method itself is rather simple:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string fileId, string extension)
{
    var location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilesDownloadLocation"];
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(location) + fileId + "." + extension;

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

The method works as expected - the first time I call it. The file is transmitted and my browser starts downloading the file.

However - if I call the same URL again from either my own computer or from any other - I get an error saying:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\...\App_Data\pdfs\test-file.pdf' because it is being used by
>   another process.

This error persists for about a minute - and then I can download the file again - but only once - and then I have to wait another minute or so until the file is unlocked.

Please note that my files are rather large (100-800 MB).

Am I missing something in my method? It almost seems like the stream locks the file for some time or something like that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because your file is locked by the first stream, you must specify a [FileShare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) that allow it to be opened by multiple streams :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string fileId, string extension)
{
    var location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilesDownloadLocation"];
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(location) + fileId + "." + extension;

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

Like that you allow multiple stream to open this file for read only.

See the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx) on that constructor overload.

Comment: If you declare the stream in a using statement, it will be disposed before the response is returned and the download will fail.

Comment: You are a lifesaver Fabien! Such a simple solution - I've just stared myself blind :)

I thought about the using-statement too - but as you mention it makes no sense because it will be disposed before the return call. 

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @JBuus You are welcome. The file stream will be disposed as soon as the content stream is, which in facts should be when the client has finished to read the response.